# How to add a description to a Data instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to add a description to my `Data` instances so I know what they're meant to be used for.
Eg: "This data is for (user.name)'s profile picture" or "This data is a encoded User instance" etc.

I was going through the properties available to `Data` instances and saw there was a `description` and `debugDescription` property. I tried to set the values for those properties but it seems like I can't since they are get-only properties. Is there any other way to add a description to a `Data` instance?

**Edit:**
Wrapping a `Data` instance as recommended below is a great solution but if there's a way to achieve the same without using a wrapper please let me know.

Comment: What do you want? What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @RajaKishan No purpose I was just curious. Also I just wanted to add description to data so you can tell what it's for. Such as if it's for an profile picture, message, or something else

Comment: You misunderstand. The `description` property is read-only. If you look in the Xcode docs you'll see that it only has a get, not a set. You use it to ask the system to provide a description of your data. It's not meant for you to add a description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a light-weight wrapper like following -

```
import Foundation

struct DescriptiveData: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let data: Data
    let customDescription: String?
    
    init(data: Data, customDescription: String? = nil) {
        self.data = data
        self.customDescription = customDescription
    }
    
    var description: String { customDescription ?? data.description }
    var debugDescription: String { description }
}
```

Usage

```
let data = DescriptiveData(data: Data(), customDescription: "data for profile picture")
print(data)
// data for profile picture
```